Anonymous function error: class java.lang.Long cannot be cast to class clojure.lang.IFn
user=> ((fn [x] x) 5)
5
user=> (#(%) 5)
Execution error (ClassCastException) at user/eval1576$fn (REPL:1).
class java.lang.Long cannot be cast to class clojure.lang.IFn (java.lang.Long is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; clojure.lang.IFn is in unnamed module of loader 'bootstrap')

I'd expected the two anonymous funtions to be equivalent. I kind of get the error in the second case: the evaluation of the anonymous function yields (5), which produces the exact same error.
However, why am I not getting this error in the first case? What's the difference?

In the first case, you're evaluating the anonymous function (which is synonymous with identity) with the argument 5, so you just get 5. In the second case your parens are unbalanced, which is odd, but the function #(%) calls its first argument, which produces the error you included, since 5 isn't a function. Check out (macroexpand-1 '#(%)) => (fn* [p1__60486#] (p1__60486#))

#(...), when there's only % inside and not other things that signify more than one argument, is equivalent to (fn [%] (...)). Not to (fn [%] ...), which you expected.
So #(%) is the same as (fn [%] (%)) - it's a function that calls its argument as a function without arguments.
